# Access to shadow DOM tree

Tags: java, selenium, shadow-dom

Can't access to element inside shadow dom.

Screenshot demonstrating how it looks:
[image: Screenshot demonstrating how it looks]

I've tried to use:

```
    WebElement root1 = DriverFactory.driver.findElement(By.tagName("downloads-manager"));       
    WebElement shadowRoot1 = expandRootElement(root1);

    WebElement root2 = shadowRoot1.findElement(By.cssSelector("iron-list"));
    WebElement shadowRoot2 = expandRootElement(root2);

    WebElement root3 = shadowRoot2.findElement(By.cssSelector("downloads-item"));
    WebElement shadowRoot3 = expandRootElement(root3);

    shadowRoot3.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='title-area' and contains(.,'Lviv')]/ancestor::div[@class='controls']/a[@id='preview']")).click();
 public WebElement expandRootElement(WebElement element) {
    WebElement ele = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) DriverFactory.driver)                
    .executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot",element);
    return ele;}
```

In result:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"downloads-item"}
```

Comment: could you add HTML text instead of image ?

Comment: browser based on chromium, but a more secured modification. It's no possibility to get HTML text, only screenshot (( 
Click on image zoom it.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: I didn't found any way how to copy HTML with shadow dom element.

Answer (score 0):

You have written wrong please refer below code

By.tagName("iron-list"))
 By.cssselectorBy.tagName("#downloads-item"));

Comment: 'iron-list' - element with id = 'downloads list'. 'downloads-item' - also element, not id

Comment: Corrected my answers please check

Answer (score 0):

You can use below Xpath

```
.//*[@id='downloads-list']/downloads-item
```

or CSS selector

```
#downloads-list>downloads-item
```

Comment: between '#downloads-list' and 'downloads-item' we have '#shadow-root' item which blocks the interaction with downgrade elements (in this case 'downloads-item') and drops - no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#downloads-list>downloads-item"}

Comment: You can try with #downloads-list>shadow-root > downloads-item on CSS Selector